# Isolating cross terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, series-expansion, expression-manipulation, approximation

I have a set of expressions that contains terms like $\frac{1}{(x + a + b)(c+d)}$.  I would like to simplify the denominator so that products of $a,b,c,d$ are dropped, but $x c$ and $x d$ are kept.  That is, the expression should be approximated as $\frac{1}{(c+d)x+a+b}$.  One obvious way to do this is to use:
`1/(Expand[Denominator[TheOriginalFraction]] /. {a*c -> 0, a*d -> 0, b*c -> 0, b*d -> 0})`.

While this works, it's clunky and inconvenient for dealing with more complicated expressions.  For example, a sum of several fractions of this form would require isolation of each fraction first, then pattern replacement, then reconstruction of the full expression.

Is there a more efficent and general method for this type of replacement/pattern matching?

Comment: There is a "typo" problem in your post : the approximated expression you give in your question does not correspond to what your code outputs. Also, according to your comment to an answer below, it is not clear what you precisely want. And, what do you exactly mean by "... fractions of this **form** ..." ?

Comment: Oops. You are correct. Thanks! I had simplified the problem I was actually solving and accidentally introduced errors!  That's embarrassing. The answers below provide enough info to do what I need.

Comment: How about you replace `a->epsilon a`, `b->epsilon b`, `c->epsilon c`, etc., then do a `Series` expansion in the denominator to first order in `epsilon`.  Then `Normal` to turn it into a regular expression, and apply `epsilon->1`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would do it:

```
expr = 1/((x + a + b) (c + d));

Limit[
  ϵ expr /. Thread[# -> ϵ #] &@Select[Variables[expr], # =!= x &],
 ϵ -> 0
]

(* ==> 1/(c x + d x) *)
```

I replaced all variables except `x` by `ϵ` times themselves and took the limit of `ϵ` times the original expression as `ϵ` goes to zero. This will leave only terms linear in the small variables in the denominator.

Comment: very clever idea:)

Comment: This is a bit off the mark, as it explicitly eliminates a and b from the expression.  It is a nice method of replacement, though.

Comment: @sm_physicist But your desired replacement is mathematically inconsistent. I assumed you wanted correct math. If not, you have to do pattern matching, but then you should be very specific about the rules for each of your variables.

Comment: @Jens +1 for reminder. I'd just use `DeleteCases[..., x]` instead of `Select`.

Comment: Sorry. I definitely made a typo, and in translating the original problem into something less ghastly, I produced some confusion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kuba Your'e right about `DeleteCases`. The `Select` just reflects my thought process... I want the variables to be happy that they got selected.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = 1/((x + a + b) (c + d));
```

Based on [clipping by total degree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22946/5478). Let me make this answer more general.

```
ClearAll@expand
Options[expand] = {"SmallTerms" -> Automatic, "Order" -> 1, "Except" -> {}};

expand[expr_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
   t,
   vars = Fold[
     DeleteCases,
     Flatten[{OptionValue["SmallTerms"]} /. Automatic -> Variables[expr] ], 
     Flatten[{OptionValue["Except"]}]]
   },
  Normal[Series[ expr /. Thread[vars -> t vars], {t, 0, OptionValue["Order"]}]
   ] /. t -> 1
  ]
```

You want to expand your denominator  so:

```
Numerator[#] / expand[Denominator[#], "Except" -> {x}] & @ expr
```

> ```
> 1/(c x + d x)
> ```

#### usage examples:

```
expand[(1 + y) (X + X^2)]
expand[(1 + y) (X + X^2), "SmallTerms" -> X]
expand[(1 + y) (X + X^2), "Except" -> X]
expand[(1 + y) (X + X^2)^6 + y^2, "Order" -> 4, "Except" -> y]
```

> ```
> X
> X+X y
> X+X^2+X y+X^2 y
> y^2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate Jens's answer. However I want to answer literally

> For example, a sum of several fractions of this form would require isolation of each fraction first, then pattern replacement, then reconstruction of the full expression.
>
> Is there a more efficent and general method for this type of replacement/pattern matching?

Here are nice functions `ExpandNumerator` and `ExpandDenominator`. They didn't reconstruct sum of fractions

```
approx[expr_] := ExpandNumerator@ExpandDenominator@expr /. 
   Except[x, a_Symbol] Except[x, b_Symbol] :> 0

(a x + b)/((x + a + b) (c + d)) + (x^2 + 
     a) b/((x + a + b + f) (x + c + d) (x + g)) // approx
```

[image]

Of course, you can write more general patter. Note that `___` is unnecesary in `Times` since it orderless.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = 1/((x + a + b) (c + d));    

ExpandAll[expr] /. Times[v1_ /; v1 =!= x, v2_ /; v2 =!= x] :> 0

(*1/(c x + d x)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
expr = 1/((x + a + b) (c + d));
expr2 = 1/((x + a + b + f) (x + c + d));
```

While not the most elegant, this appears to do the trick

```
simpliFunc = Numerator[#] /
  Plus @@ Thread[
    Times[
      x^# & /@ Range[Length@Rest@CoefficientList[Expand@Denominator[#], {x}]],
      Rest@CoefficientList[ Expand@Denominator[#], {x}]
    ]
  ] &

simpliFunc@expr
```

[image]

Combined...

```
simpliFunc/@ (expr+expr2)
```

[image]

More complex examples:

```
expr4 = (a x + b)/((x + a + b) (c + d));
expr5 = (x^2 + x^b)/((x + a + b + f) (x + c + d));
expr6 = (b^x)/((x + a + b + f + g x^2) (x + c + d));

simpliFunc /@ (expr4 + expr5 + expr6)
```

[image]