# MatchQ[x y, (x | y) (x | y)] returns False

Tags: pattern-matching

```
MatchQ[x y, (x | y) (x | y)]
```

It returns false. Why?

I want to eliminate terms like `x^2`, `y^2`, `z^2`, `x y`, `x z`, `y z`.

Comment: I think because `(x | y) (x | y)` evaluates to `(x | y)^2`, which doesn't match your expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to eliminate terms like x^2, y^2, z^2, x y, x z, y z"?

Comment: Does `MatchQ[#, _^2 | a_ b_] & /@ {x^2, y^2, z^2, x y, x z, y z}` do what you want? Your post needs more information, because there is an inconsistency between the terms you want to eliminate and the patterns you are making. Do you want to eliminate any second-degree monomial? Or do you want to eliminate any second-order monomial that involves `x` or `y`? (or `x` *or* `y` and nothing else)?

Comment: Btw: `MatchQ[x y, HoldPattern[(x | y) (x | y)]]`

Comment: For more info, the reason @Kuba 's method works is to avoid the problem march mentioned.

Comment: For more info, the reason Kuba 's method works is to avoid the problem @march mentioned.

Comment: @march, your first comment should be an answer, along with Kuba's solution using `HoldPattern`.

Comment: @SimonWoods I'm not sure if `Verbatim` isn't more apropriated, I'm often confused.

Comment: @SimonWoods. I wanted to wait to answer until I get the my clarification question answered. The OP is using `x` and `y` explicitly in their attempt at a pattern but they want `z^2` matched, so I'm not actually sure what they want. In addition, depending on the actual application of this, it might be that using `MatchQ` just isn't the way to go in the first place. I guess I did answer the original query, though, so perhaps I'll write an answer anyway.

Comment: What I originally had was as follows.

pat = x | y | z | a | b | c;
series = 1 + x + 2 y + 3 z + 4 a + 5 b + 6 c + 7 x^2 + 8 y^2 + 9 z^2 + 10 x b + 11 a b c + 12 x y b^5 /. pat pat -> 0
I expected 1 + x + 2 y + 3 z + 4 a + 5 b + 6 c. But it did not work.

Comment: @ march, yes it does. But suppose I have 20 possible variables instead of just x y z.

Comment: @ Kuba, yes. But your solution won't eliminate x^2 or y^2.

Comment: @PetraAxolotl. I'm pretty sure the solution `MatchQ[ expression , a_ b_ | a_^2]` in my answer does what you want, for any number of variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you `Trace` the evaluation sequence of this expression, you get the following:

```
Trace@MatchQ[x y, (x | y) (x | y)]
(* {{(x|y) (x|y), (x|y)^2}, MatchQ[x y, (x|y)^2], False} *)
```

This shows that `(x|y) (x|y)` gets evaluated to `(x|y)^2` before the pattern matching occurs, and `x y` doesn't match `(x|y)^2`, although `x^2` and `y^2` will:

```
MatchQ[#, (x | y) (x | y)] & /@ {x^2, y^2, z^2, x y, x z, y z}
(* {True, True, False, False, False, False} *)
```

If you really want all of the expressions in that list above to match, I would do something like

```
MatchQ[#, a_ b_ | a_^2] & /@ {x^2, y^2, z^2, x y, x z, y z}
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: If the user wants to capture only `x` and `y`, a little work is required: `MatchQ[#, a_ (b_ /; MatchQ[b, x | y]) | a_^2 /; MatchQ[a, x | y]] &`.

Comment: @rcollyer. Or `MatchQ[#, a_ b_ | a_^2 /; And[Or[a == x, a == y], Or[b == x, b == y]]] &`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to create a function that can match something like $x x$ or $x y$ in a simple way.

So, here's my answer and hope this can help you:

```
f = Function[{t, l}, With[{pat = Alternatives @@ l},MatchQ[Unevaluated@t, HoldPattern[pat pat]]],HoldFirst];
f[x x, {x, y, z}]
f[x z, {x, y, z}]
```

Also, I think you would love to use something like Map:

```
f[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ (Unevaluated /@Unevaluated[{x x, x y, y y, z y}])
```

Can this help?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone!

Eventually I found the solution at [Dropping Higher Order Terms in symbolic evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/dropping-higher-order-terms-in-symbolic-evaluation).

The one using

```
Normal[Series[expr /. Thread[vars -> t*vars], {t, 0, 10}]] /. t -> 1
```

My final code (for getting the components of the Riemann tensor of a certain weak gravitational field) became.

```
Needs["GREATER2`"];
X = {t, x, y, w};
ds2 = -(1 + 2 \[Phi][t, x, y, w]) dt^2 + (1 - 2 \[Phi][t, x, y, w]) (dx^2 + dy^2 + dw^2);
Gdd = Metric[ds2, X];
termPattern = Join[{\[Phi][t, x, y, w]}, Flatten[D[\[Phi][t, x, y, w], {{t, x, y, w}, 1}]], Flatten[D[\[Phi][t, x, y, w], {{t, x, y, w}, 2}]]];
Result = Raise[Riemann[Gdd, X], 1, Gdd];
ResultFirstOrder = Normal[Series[Result /. Thread[termPattern -> i*termPattern], {i, 0, 1}]] /. {i -> 1, \[Phi]_[t, x, y, w] -> \[Phi]}
```

Comment: ...this turned out to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why didn't you ask about this to begin with?