# What resources can I use to become familiar with high level syntax?

Tags: programming, syntax, core-language

I was reading a question about [dropping higher order terms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/dropping-higher-order-terms-in-symbolic-evaluation) and realized that I have a serous gap in knowledge when it comes to the finer points of mathematica computational programming. Are there any starter sources on this I should know, besides the tutorial on the wolfram language given on the [Mathematica Website](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/notebook-documents/)?

edit: I would have commented on the particular answer asking the user for a resource, but I think it would be off topic.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, [The tutorial](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/pure-functions/) had exactly what I needed! Answers still welcome for alternate sources though.